# Knockout event binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, event-binding

I want to bind myFunction with change or onchange event.

This is the function which I want to bind, inside my ViewModel:

```
myFunction: function spinSeconds(event, ui) {
  if (ui.value >= 60) {
      $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
      $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp');
      return false;
  } else if (ui.value < 0) {
      $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
      $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
      return false;
  }
}
```

I am calling this function inside openModal() function:

```
function openModal() {

    //
    //some code here
    //

    $('#seconds').spinner({
        spin: spinSeconds
    });
}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <input id="seconds" value=10 size=2 data-bind="value: PreExecWaitMin, event: {change: myFunction}" /> minutes
</div>
```

And I am facing with this error:

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "event: function (){return {change:myFunction} }"
>   Message: spinSeconds is not defined'

I've searched many event binding examples but could not handle it for my issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am using these spinners: http://jsfiddle.net/xHzMw/228/ I think it is proper to use change event for binding.

Answer (score 1):

[The first argument to an event-bound function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function) is `$data`. The second is the event. But the way to observe change events on an input is to [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the bound `value`:

> For advanced users, if you want to register your own subscriptions to
>   be notified of changes to observables, you can call their subscribe
>   function. For example:
>
> ```
> myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
>     alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
> });
> ```
>
> The subscribe function is how many parts of KO work internally. Most
>   of the time you don’t need to use this, because the built-in bindings
>   and templating system take care of managing subscriptions.

More likely, the solution is to set up a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) based on the value-bound variable. The subscription is implicit.

It would be better if `spinner` had its own custom binding handler, though you can probably get away with this, as it seems to be just a visual effect. jQuery selectors are a significant code smell in Knockout.

Comment: For completeness, please include an example of subscription.

Comment: @Michael See expanded answer